# Adding order number to woocommerce admin email header in <h1> tags

Tags: php, json, wordpress, email, woocommerce

Trying to add order number to a woocommerce admin new order email header. Thought to be easy, but when adding following code

```
<?php if ( ! $sent_to_admin ) : ?>
    <h2><?php printf( __( 'Order #%s', 'woocommerce' ), $order->get_order_number() ); ?></h2>
<?php else : ?>
    <h2><a class="link" href="<?php echo esc_url( admin_url( 'post.php?post=' . $order->get_id() . '&action=edit' ) ); ?>"><?php printf( __( 'Order #%s', 'woocommerce' ), $order->get_order_number() ); ?></a> (<?php printf( '<time datetime="%s">%s</time>', $order->get_date_created()->format( 'c' ), wc_format_datetime( $order->get_date_created() ) ); ?>)</h2>
<?php endif; ?>
```

to **email-header.php** in h1 tags, I'm getting "**SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data**" during checkout. 
Is there some sort of conflict maybe? Or some code I'm missing?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The email header ( not(!) the subject ) can be modified using the WooCommerce settings.

Go to WooCommerce -> Settings -> Email (tab)

From there click on the "New Order" email to modify it. Where it says "email heading" you can use

```
{order_number}
```

to output the order number in the heading.